# Live Streaming MPD Contain Misalignment Segment Start Time

Tags: video-streaming, live-streaming, wowza, mpeg-dash

Live streaming (MPEG-DASH) provide MPD file that contain different segment start time.

I am streaming 9 streams of 3 different resolutions (27 streams total) and i am using Wowza packager.

My MPD file contain 3 adaptation sets and each adaptation set contain a SegmentTimeline (List of segments)-

The first segment have "t" (time) and "d" (duration).

So, totally we have 3 first-segments with "t" attribute (for each adaptation set).

the value of one of them is not equal to the 2 others.

Here is my MPD file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<MPD xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xmlns="urn:mpeg:dash:schema:mpd:2011"
     xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
     xsi:schemaLocation="urn:mpeg:DASH:schema:MPD:2011 http://standards.iso.org/ittf/PubliclyAvailableStandards/MPEG-DASH_schema_files/DASH-MPD.xsd"
     profiles="urn:mpeg:dash:profile:isoff-live:2011"
     type="dynamic"
     minimumUpdatePeriod="PT1.489S" 
     publishTime="2019-06-06T12:55:32Z" 
     availabilityStartTime="2019-06-06T12:15:43Z" 
     timeShiftBufferDepth="PT25.0S"
     suggestedPresentationDelay="PT1.0S" 
     minBufferTime="PT6.0S">
<ProgramInformation>
    <Title>camera1.smil</Title>
</ProgramInformation>
<Location>http://...:1935/..../smil:camera1.smil/manifest_w1997958089.mpd</Location>
<Period id="0" start="PT0.0S">
    <AdaptationSet id="0" group="1" mimeType="video/mp4" width="3200" height="640" par="1:1" frameRate="30" segmentAlignment="true" startWithSAP="1" subsegmentAlignment="true" subsegmentStartsWithSAP="1">
        <SegmentTemplate timescale="90000" media="chunk_ctvideo_cfm4s_rid$RepresentationID$_cs$Time$_w1997958089_mpd.m4s" initialization="chunk_ctvideo_cfm4s_rid$RepresentationID$_cinit_w1997958089_mpd.m4s">
            <SegmentTimeline>
                <S t="212758470" d="45000"/>
                <S d="45000"/>
                <S d="45000"/>
                <S d="45000"/>
                <S d="45000"/>
                <S d="45000"/>
                <S d="45000"/>
                <S d="45000"/>
                <S d="45000"/>
                <S d="45000"/>
                <S d="45000"/>
                <S d="45000"/>
                <S d="45000"/>
                <S d="45000"/>
                <S d="45000"/>
                <S d="45000"/>
                <S d="45000"/>
                <S d="45000"/>
                <S d="45000"/>
                <S d="45000"/>
                <S d="45000"/>
                <S d="45000"/>
                <S d="45000"/>
                <S d="45000"/>
                <S d="45000"/>
                <S d="45000"/>
                <S d="45000"/>
                <S d="45000"/>
                <S d="45000"/>
                <S d="45000"/>
                <S d="45000"/>
                <S d="45000"/>
                <S d="45000"/>
                <S d="45000"/>
                <S d="45000"/>
                <S d="45000"/>
                <S d="45000"/>
                <S d="45000"/>
                <S d="45000"/>
                <S d="45000"/>
                <S d="45000"/>
                <S d="45000"/>
                <S d="45000"/>
                <S d="45000"/>
                <S d="45000"/>
                <S d="45000"/>
                <S d="45000"/>
                <S d="45000"/>
                <S d="45000"/>
                <S d="45000"/>
            </SegmentTimeline>
        </SegmentTemplate>
        <Representation id="p0va0br3000000" codecs="avc1.640033" sar="1:1" bandwidth="3000000" />
        <Representation id="p0va0br3100000" codecs="avc1.640033" sar="1:1" bandwidth="3100000" />
        <Representation id="p0va0br3500000" codecs="avc1.640033" sar="1:1" bandwidth="3500000" />
        <Representation id="p0va0br4200000" codecs="avc1.640033" sar="1:1" bandwidth="4200000" />
        <Representation id="p0va0br4300000" codecs="avc1.640033" sar="1:1" bandwidth="4300000" />
        <Representation id="p0va0br4150000" codecs="avc1.640033" sar="1:1" bandwidth="4150000" />
        <Representation id="p0va0br3400000" codecs="avc1.640033" sar="1:1" bandwidth="3400000" />
        <Representation id="p0va0br2900000" codecs="avc1.640033" sar="1:1" bandwidth="2900000" />
        <Representation id="p0va0br2800000" codecs="avc1.640033" sar="1:1" bandwidth="2800000" />
    </AdaptationSet>
    <AdaptationSet id="1" group="1" mimeType="video/mp4" width="3200" height="320" par="1:1" frameRate="30" segmentAlignment="true" startWithSAP="1" subsegmentAlignment="true" subsegmentStartsWithSAP="1">
        <SegmentTemplate timescale="90000" media="chunk_ctvideo_cfm4s_rid$RepresentationID$_cs$Time$_w1997958089_mpd.m4s" initialization="chunk_ctvideo_cfm4s_rid$RepresentationID$_cinit_w1997958089_mpd.m4s">
            <SegmentTimeline>
                <S t="212713470" d="45000"/>
                <S d="45000"/>
                <S d="45000"/>
                <S d="45000"/>
                <S d="45000"/>
                <S d="45000"/>
                <S d="45000"/>
                <S d="45000"/>
                <S d="45000"/>
                <S d="45000"/>
                <S d="45000"/>
                <S d="45000"/>
                <S d="45000"/>
                <S d="45000"/>
                <S d="45000"/>
                <S d="45000"/>
                <S d="45000"/>
                <S d="45000"/>
                <S d="45000"/>
                <S d="45000"/>
                <S d="45000"/>
                <S d="45000"/>
                <S d="45000"/>
                <S d="45000"/>
                <S d="45000"/>
                <S d="45000"/>
                <S d="45000"/>
                <S d="45000"/>
                <S d="45000"/>
                <S d="45000"/>
                <S d="45000"/>
                <S d="45000"/>
                <S d="45000"/>
                <S d="45000"/>
                <S d="45000"/>
                <S d="45000"/>
                <S d="45000"/>
                <S d="45000"/>
                <S d="45000"/>
                <S d="45000"/>
                <S d="45000"/>
                <S d="45000"/>
                <S d="45000"/>
                <S d="45000"/>
                <S d="45000"/>
                <S d="45000"/>
                <S d="45000"/>
                <S d="45000"/>
                <S d="45000"/>
                <S d="45000"/>
            </SegmentTimeline>
        </SegmentTemplate>
        <Representation id="p0va1br1310000" codecs="avc1.640033" sar="1:1" bandwidth="1310000" />
        <Representation id="p0va1br1320000" codecs="avc1.640033" sar="1:1" bandwidth="1320000" />
        <Representation id="p0va1br1340000" codecs="avc1.640033" sar="1:1" bandwidth="1340000" />
        <Representation id="p0va1br1840000" codecs="avc1.640033" sar="1:1" bandwidth="1840000" />
        <Representation id="p0va1br1850000" codecs="avc1.640033" sar="1:1" bandwidth="1850000" />
        <Representation id="p0va1br1860000" codecs="avc1.640033" sar="1:1" bandwidth="1860000" />
        <Representation id="p0va1br1870000" codecs="avc1.640033" sar="1:1" bandwidth="1870000" />
        <Representation id="p0va1br1380000" codecs="avc1.640033" sar="1:1" bandwidth="1380000" />
        <Representation id="p0va1br1390000" codecs="avc1.640033" sar="1:1" bandwidth="1390000" />
    </AdaptationSet>
    <AdaptationSet id="2" group="1" mimeType="video/mp4" width="3200" height="160" par="1:1" frameRate="30" segmentAlignment="true" startWithSAP="1" subsegmentAlignment="true" subsegmentStartsWithSAP="1">
        <SegmentTemplate timescale="90000" media="chunk_ctvideo_cfm4s_rid$RepresentationID$_cs$Time$_w1997958089_mpd.m4s" initialization="chunk_ctvideo_cfm4s_rid$RepresentationID$_cinit_w1997958089_mpd.m4s">
            <SegmentTimeline>
                <S t="212758470" d="45000"/>
                <S d="45000"/>
                <S d="45000"/>
                <S d="45000"/>
                <S d="45000"/>
                <S d="45000"/>
                <S d="45000"/>
                <S d="45000"/>
                <S d="45000"/>
                <S d="45000"/>
                <S d="45000"/>
                <S d="45000"/>
                <S d="45000"/>
                <S d="45000"/>
                <S d="45000"/>
                <S d="45000"/>
                <S d="45000"/>
                <S d="45000"/>
                <S d="45000"/>
                <S d="45000"/>
                <S d="45000"/>
                <S d="45000"/>
                <S d="45000"/>
                <S d="45000"/>
                <S d="45000"/>
                <S d="45000"/>
                <S d="45000"/>
                <S d="45000"/>
                <S d="45000"/>
                <S d="45000"/>
                <S d="45000"/>
                <S d="45000"/>
                <S d="45000"/>
                <S d="45000"/>
                <S d="45000"/>
                <S d="45000"/>
                <S d="45000"/>
                <S d="45000"/>
                <S d="45000"/>
                <S d="45000"/>
                <S d="45000"/>
                <S d="45000"/>
                <S d="45000"/>
                <S d="45000"/>
                <S d="45000"/>
                <S d="45000"/>
                <S d="45000"/>
                <S d="45000"/>
                <S d="45000"/>
                <S d="45000"/>
            </SegmentTimeline>
        </SegmentTemplate>
        <Representation id="p0va2br151000" codecs="avc1.640033" sar="1:1" bandwidth="151000" />
        <Representation id="p0va2br252000" codecs="avc1.640033" sar="1:1" bandwidth="252000" />
        <Representation id="p0va2br483000" codecs="avc1.640033" sar="1:1" bandwidth="483000" />
        <Representation id="p0va2br584000" codecs="avc1.640033" sar="1:1" bandwidth="584000" />
        <Representation id="p0va2br585000" codecs="avc1.640033" sar="1:1" bandwidth="585000" />
        <Representation id="p0va2br586000" codecs="avc1.640033" sar="1:1" bandwidth="586000" />
        <Representation id="p0va2br487000" codecs="avc1.640033" sar="1:1" bandwidth="487000" />
        <Representation id="p0va2br258000" codecs="avc1.640033" sar="1:1" bandwidth="258000" />
        <Representation id="p0va2br159000" codecs="avc1.640033" sar="1:1" bandwidth="159000" />
    </AdaptationSet>
</Period>
<UTCTiming schemeIdUri="urn:mpeg:dash:utc:direct:2014" value="2019-06-06T12:55:32Z"/>
</MPD>
```

You can see the misalignment:

```
<S t="212758470" d="45000"/>
```

```
<S t="212713470" d="45000"/>
```

```
<S t="212758470" d="45000"/>
```

My questions is:

- This is valid situation?
- If yes, What the reason for this misalignment?
- If no, How can I fix it?

Please note that this misalignment not happened in all MPD's, its happened sometimes.

My goal is getting exactly same SegmentTemplate for each adaptation set.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed the middle adaptation set (id=1) is ahead by 0.5s of two others. It's worth mentioning that each segment has duration equal exactly to 0.5s.

Assuming that GOP intervals are equal to 0.5s, what deprives Packager to align adaptation sets? Perhaps audio streams? Is audio included? if so i suggest disable audio and re-check. 
i also suggest asking Wowza experts how adaptation sets alignment is performed.

Comment: As you can see on this MPD file- There is no audio streaming. Ticket on wowza already opened. But i am still waiting for wisdom of the crowd